# Change JVM logs path use jython

Tags: websphere, jython, websphere-8, wsadmin

I would like to change path JVM logs in WebSphere 8.5.5.

Via GUI in: Logging and tracing > NorkomServer > JVM Logs.

There is:

Information required File Name: 
${SERVER_LOG_ROOT}/SystemOut.log

I have to change it to: "/opt/logs/SystemOut.log"

Instead use "sed", i must use jython. Any help, please ?

Answer (score 0):

You can run the below wsadmin script (with -lang jython) to update the default file path for SystemOut.log file.

```
#Update the below Environment variables before running this script

#Enter the nodename below
nodename=''
#Enter the servername below
servername=''
#Set the updated file path below
filename='/opt/logs/SystemOut.log'

#Set the Stream name 
#outputStreamRedirect for SystemOut & errorStreamRedirect for SystemError
streamName = 'outputStreamRedirect'

#get the server Id
serverId = AdminConfig.getid('/Cell:/Node:'+nodename+'/Server:'+servername+'')
#get the Stream Id
streamId = AdminConfig.showAttribute(serverId, streamName)

#update the file path
AdminConfig.modify(streamId, [['fileName', filename]])
#Save the changes
AdminConfig.save()
```

Restart JVM post this change.